# How to create custom icon using react-leaflet-pixi-overlay?

Tags: reactjs, pixi.js, react-leaflet

React leaflet Pixi overlay takes only these object props:  id, position, iconColor, popup, popupOpen, onClick and tooltip. So how to create a custom marker icon? There is no prop for passing icon marker.

Here is the link for the same https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-pixi-overlay

Can any one please help?

Comment: Did any one know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

the "new version" from last year is supporting custom icons now, just update and do it like the example
https://github.com/knapcio/react-leaflet-pixi-overlay#custom-icon

```
const markers = [{
            id: 'someIDUniqueToMarker',
            iconId: 'someIDUniqueToIcon', // used for cache
            customIcon:  '<svg style="-webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4));filter: drop-shadow( 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4));" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="red" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 0c-4.198 0-8 3.403-8 7.602 0 6.243 6.377 6.903 8 16.398 1.623-9.495 8-10.155 8-16.398 0-4.199-3.801-7.602-8-7.602zm0 11c-1.657 0-3-1.343-3-3s1.342-3 3-3 3 1.343 3 3-1.343 3-3 3z"/></svg>'
        },
    ];
```